# Quotes for Low volume (>500) LCD displays

Tags: lcd

I am trying to find quotes for low volume displays, Graphic lcd's specifically, but I am interested in touch screen panels too. I found Vishay but cannot see any prices anywhere. I am curious what the big name companies do for their graphic LCD's, and how they determine what lcd to use. Do they fabricate their own displays, or purchase the displays from other companies?

Also, any opinions on how to choose a display for a low volume product? 
What were your past experiences with choosing a graphic display, and what advice can you give?

Comment: What kind of customization you want? Why not just taking standard ones?

Comment: What do you mean when you're talking
about a customized graphic LCD? 
Specifically, what displays have you
looked at already that you have
rejected?  Why did you reject
them--what are your unique
requirements?

Comment: Nobody fabricates their own graphic
LCDs; even the highest volume
customers buy from one of a handful of
manufacturers; Sharp, NEC, Toshiba,
Hitachi, LG Display, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for ~500-1000 display panels with the intent to buy, I would *strongly* suggest speaking with an account manager, sales rep, and/or applications engineer at a distributor.  Such an order will likely generate enough revenue for them to give you a whole lot more than the time of day.  I know the local account managers and FAE's for a few large component distributors in my area ([Future Electronics](http://www.futureelectronics.com/) and [Allied Electronics](http://www.alliedelec.com/)), and they are usually helpful, though not always prompt.

Looking at Future, they do seem to have a few LCDs quoted on their site, however it is certainly not a comprehensive list.  If you contact a sales rep (there or anywhere) and provide them your requirements, they may come back with additional parts that their manufacturers produce that better fit your need.

Unless your volumes are going to be in the millions, let me dispel any thoughts you have of "Why not just talk to (LCD mfc) directly?".  Said manufacturers will *not* care about you, and the premium they will charge to deal with you (if they bother at all) will be *higher* than what a typical distributor would, because, frankly, they **do not want** your direct business.  Use the middlemen.  They will make specifying, finding, and sourcing LCD panels vastly easier and cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

Alas, many companies inexplicably neglect to post prices on their website, replacing it with the phrase "call for a quote".

A few companies that have prices for LCD displays on their website:

- http://www.newhavendisplay.com/ (prices for 1, call for bulk quantity price)
- http://www.crystalfontz.com/ (prices in 1, 10, 500, etc)
- http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/76 (prices in 1, 10, 100)
- http://www.newark.com/graphic (prices in 1, 10, 100)
- http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Cat=524918 (prices in 1, 10, 100, etc)
- http://www.jameco.com/
- http://www.mouser.com/Search/Refine.aspx?Keyword=LCD+graphic+display
- http://www.alliedelec.com/search/searchresults.aspx?N=0&Ntk=Primary&Ntt=LCD+graphic+display
- http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/category/365/LCDs-Liquid-Crystal-Displays/1.html
- http://www.futurlec.com/LCDDisp.shtml
- http://www.tvielectronics.com/ (prices in 1, 25)

Comment: I can personally vouch for Newhaven, they're a good US-based distributor with excellent support and good prices. I was going to post an answer naming them specifically, but I'll just leave it as a comment to your answer.

Comment: It's not inexplicable - they want their salespeople to probe you, prod you and try to get you to buy things you weren't planning on.  It's not helpful, but it's not inexplicable.